# Webgrid with filtered results

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, webgrid

I like the Webgrid HTML-Helper in Razor-ViewEngine.

Unfortunatly I am facing a problem. Using the built-in sorting and paging functions I loose my filter settings.

Above the grid I have a filtercontrol (form), filtering the rows shown in the grid by filling a filter-class and calling an actionmethode on the controller when submitting.

Code in Controller:

```
public ActionResult DeliveryContractList(SampleClassFilter filter){

   // Populate a filtered List of Items to Show    
   IList<SampleClass> model = FillList(filter);

   // Return a View with the List.
   return View("SampleClassList", model);

}
```

The View:

```
  @model IEnumerable<SampleClass>
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "SampleClassList";
  }

  @using(Html.BeginForm()){
        // Form to Set the Filter
        ...
  }

  <div id = "SampleClassList">

    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "SampleClassList");

    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new {id = "gridSampleClass"}, columns:
        grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Foo", "For", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Bar", "Bar", canSort: true),
        )
     ); 
</div>
```

I recognized that when clicking e.g. the column header of the grid to sort the action methode in the controller is called too. Of course the filter class is null leading to an unfiltered resultset.

Is there a way to keep my results filtered when sorting or paging the webgrid?
I don't want to use jquery!!!

Thanks in advance
Tobi

---

Is it possible to define parameters added to the link called when clicking on a sort or page link?

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer below?

Comment: Does anyone have the answer to this??

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha.  The problem is that you need to add a GET form around both your filter fields and the web grid.  And then you need to do a tiny bit of massaging the webgrid data so that it posts its sorting info back in a way that it recognizes.  I lost the link to the article I read about this, but I have an example here: [ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid - custom, server-side sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121735/asp-net-mvc3-webgrid-custom-server-side-sorting/10759799#10759799)

You end up with urls like localhost/example/admin/thing?thingName=Hyatt&City=&State=TX&Country=&sort=city&sortdir=ASC