# ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid - custom, server-side sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, razor, webgrid

Is there a way to override default MVC3 WebGrid sorting behavior to call my controller (which will perform server side sorting and return the data) when sort is called?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Let me know if the answer below is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass the server side sorted data to the webgrid, along with the info on how many records there are.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx has a helpful walkthrough.  I'm doing database level sorting/filtering/paging to minimize the amount of data being passed around.  I don't think my webserver would love me if I passed all 70,000 objects a customer has just so they can see the 25 on page 1.  This is pretty much everything you need, except the very lightweight view model that just wraps your IEnumerable collection with some extra paging data.

Since web grid just uses the query string vars to decide what to do you need to use a get method form.  And you need to include the sort field/direction in querystring in a way webgrid knows how to read it.  So you end up with urls like localhost/example/admin/thing?thingName=Hyatt&City=&State=TX&Country=&sort=city&sortdir=ASC

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string thingName, string city, string state, string country, int page = 1)
            {
                const int pageSize = 25;                
                int totalRecords = 0; 
                IEnumerable<Thing> things = ThingModel.GetPagedSortedLocationsForCustomer(customerId, sort, sortdir, out totalRecords, pageSize, page, thingName, city, state, country);

                PagedThings viewModel = new PagedThings(pageSize, page, totalRecords, things);

                return View(viewModel);
            }
```

View:

```
@model ExampleCompany.Area.ViewModels.PagedThings 

@{  



using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ThingaMaBob", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Get))
{

    <label for="ThingName">ThingName</label>@Html.TextBox("ThingName", "")
    <label for="City">City</label>@Html.TextBox("City", "")
    <label for="State">State</label>@Html.TextBox("State", "")
    <label for="Country">Country</label>@Html.TextBox("Country", "")
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />

    <br />
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canSort: true);
    grid.Bind(Model.Things, rowCount: Model.TotalRows, autoSortAndPage: false);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

        @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid"},
        columns: grid.Columns(
            //ommitted
            grid.Column("thingName", "Thing"),
        ));

    Html.Hidden(grid.SortFieldName, grid.SortColumn);
    Html.Hidden(grid.SortDirectionFieldName, grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC");
}
```

Model:

```
public static IEnumerable<Thing> GetPagedSortedThingsForCustomer(int customerid, String sortby, String sorttype, out int totalRecords, int pageSize, int pageIndex, string thingName, string city, string state, string country)
        {
            var tmp = new List<Thing>();
            int total = 0;

            dynamic dr = OurDBUtility.ReturnDR("ExampleProc_GetThingsSortedPaged", ConnectionInfo.ExampleConnection, customerid, sortby, sorttype, pageSize, pageIndex, thingName, city, state, country);
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var tmpThing = new Thing();
                    tmpThing.LoadFromDr(dr);
                    tmp.Add(tmpThing);
                    if (total == 0)
                    {
                        total = (int)dr["TOTAL_THINGS"];
                    }
                }
            }
            totalRecords = total;

            return tmp;
        }
```

Proc with dynamic sql - yes, you could use Linq-to-Sql or other techniques if you wanted to, but i'm old school:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE ExampleProc_GetThingsSortedPaged
      ( @CustomerId  int
       , @sortby    nvarchar(60)
      , @sorttype   nvarchar(60)
      , @pageSize int
      , @pageIndex int
      , @thingName nvarchar(255) = null
      , @city nvarchar(30) = null
      , @state nvarchar(30) = null
      , @country char(2) = null
      )
    as

        DECLARE @strSql      nvarchar(3000) 
        --calculate paging rows
        declare @startRow int, @endRow int
        --e.g. if you have a page size of 10, page 1 = 1 - 10, page 2 = 11 -20 
        set @startRow = ((@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize) + 1
        set @endRow = @startRow + @pageSize - 1

        if @thingName = ''
            set @thingName = null
        if @city = ''
            set @city = null
        if @state = ''
            set @state = null
        if @country = ''
            set @country = null

        --return total for webgrid, accounting for filter
        declare @totalThings int
        select @totalThings = COUNT(*)
        from EXAMPLE_TABLE T with(nolock)
        where CUSTOMER_ID = @CustomerId
            AND (T.THING_NAME LIKE @thingName + '%' OR @thingName is null)              
            AND (T.CITY LIKE @city + '%' or @city is null) 
            AND (T.STATE LIKE @state + '%' or @state is null) 
            AND (T.COUNTRY = @country or @country is null)



        DECLARE @ParameterDefinition AS NVARCHAR(200)


        set @ParameterDefinition = '@totalThings int, @CustomerId INT, @startRow INT, @endRow INT, @thingName nvarchar(255), @city nvarchar(30), @state nvarchar(30), @country char(2)'

        --When we need to do dynamic sql it is better to use paramterization, but you cannot do (ORDER BY @sortBy).     
        SET @strSql = N'SELECT * from
                        (
                        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.' + @sortby + ' ' + @sorttype + ') as Row, 
                            @totalThings  [TOTAL_THINGS],
                             T.THING_ID, T.THING_NAME, T.ADDRESS, T.CITY,  T.STATE, 
                            T.ZIP_CODE, T.COUNTRY 
                        FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE T
                        WHERE T.CUSTOMER_ID = @CustomerId 
                          AND (T.THING_NAME LIKE @thingName + ''%'' OR @thingName is null)              
                          AND (T.CITY LIKE @city + ''%'' or @city is null) 
                          AND (T.STATE LIKE @state + ''%'' or @state is null) 
                          AND (T.COUNTRY = @country or @country is null)
                           ) paged
                        where Row between @startRow and @endRow 
                        ORDER BY Row'

        --print @strSql
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @strSql, @ParameterDefinition, @totalThings, @CustomerId, @startRow, @endRow, @thingName, @city, @state, @country


    GO
```

Proc with CTE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExampleProc_GetThingsSortedPaged
  ( @CustomerID  int
  , @sortby    nvarchar(60)
  , @sorttype   nvarchar(60)
  , @pageSize int = 25
  , @pageIndex int = 1
  , @thingName nvarchar(255) = null
  , @city varchar(30) = null
  , @state nvarchar(30) = null
  , @country char(2) = null
  )
as



declare @startRow int
declare @endRow int

SET @startRow = ((@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize) + 1;
SET @endRow = @startRow + @pageSize - 1;

set @sortby = replace(LOWER(@sortby), '_', '')
SET @sorttype = LOWER(@sorttype)

if @sorttype != 'asc' and @sorttype != 'desc'
begin
      set @sorttype = 'asc'
end

;with cte_things as (
      SELECT 
            CASE
                  WHEN @sortby ='country' AND @sorttype = 'asc'  then row_number() over (order by C.COUNTRY_NAME ASC)
                  WHEN @sortby ='country' AND @sorttype = 'desc' then row_number() over (order by C.COUNTRY_NAME DESC)

                  WHEN @sortby ='state' AND @sorttype = 'asc'  then row_number() over (order by STATE ASC) 
                  WHEN @sortby ='state' AND @sorttype = 'desc' then row_number() over (order by STATE DESC)

                  WHEN @sortby ='city' AND @sorttype = 'asc'  then row_number() over (order by CITY ASC)
                  WHEN @sortby ='city' AND @sorttype = 'desc' then row_number() over (order by CITY DESC)

                  WHEN @sortby ='thingname' AND @sorttype = 'desc' then row_number() over (order by THING_NAME DESC) 
                  ELSE row_number() over (order by THING_NAME ASC)
            END AS Row
            ,T.THING_ID, T.THING_NAME, T.THING_TYPE, T.ADDRESS, T.CITY, T.STATE
            , T.ZIP_CODE, T.COUNTRY_CODE, C.COUNTRY_NAME, T.PHONE_NUMBER
            , T.LATITUDE, T.LONGITUDE
            FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE L 
            join COUNTRIES C 
                  on C.COUNTRY_CODE = L.COUNTRY_CODE
            where
                  T.CUSTOMER_ID = @CustomerId 
                  and L.CITY = ISNULL(@city, CITY)
                  and L.STATE = ISNULL(@state, STATE)
                  and L.COUNTRY_CODE = ISNULL(@country, L.COUNTRY_CODE)
                  and L.THING_NAME = ISNULL(@thingName, THING_NAME)
)
, cte_total as (select COUNT(*) as TOTAL_THINGS from cte_things)
, cte_all as (select cte_things.*, cte_total.TOTAL_THINGS from cte_things cross join cte_total)

SELECT * FROM cte_all
where
      Row >= @startRow
      and Row <= @endRow  
ORDER BY Row



GO
```

Comment: Aha! I've been searching for an example of a WebGrid with filtering and server-side paging.  Thanks for that.

Comment: I keep seeing crazy examples where people just put a "filter" text box.  Apparently they want their users to type in the filter using either their database column name or model name.  That seems very dangerous to me.  Anyway, minor update.  I'm going to get rid of the dynamic sql and build a paramterized query in .net, so that I don't have to hardcode in a condition on City when I'm not filtering on city.  And yeah you can eliminate it in dynamic sql, but it makes the @parameterDefinition trickier to handle.

Comment: Exposing column names to the users seems dangerous and unfriendly!  But there you go.  Regarding the DB bit, I'd recommend you invest some time in Entity Framework Linq to entities.  I'm old school like you so I took some persuading, but I love it now.

Comment: We like to know exactly what sql is going to run before it runs.  I haven't looked into EF.  But with plain Linq it seemed very easy to think that you were querying objects and actually be querying the database.

Comment: True enough, it does provide a level of abstraction that could be dangerous.  For areas of the application that are performance critical I agree it's probably best to stick to the traditional route.  But as for the inevitable mountain of maintenance forms that get used only occasionally, I'm prepared to compromise.

Comment: I have an update for the proc.  Someone finally figured out how to make it work with a non-dynamic CTE :)  Adding above