# Display Paging In ASP.NET GridView Even with a single Page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

In My Database I Have 10000000 Records. In GridView First I Am Showing First 10 Records. In Order To See the Next Records User Need to Click Page Numbers ( 1,2,3,------10000). But As I'm Retrieving 10 Records for The First Time GridView Paging is not Showing.

Is There Any Way To Show Paging In ASP.NET GridView Statically ?

Comment: How did you get 10000000000000000 records in your database without having some way of seeing what's in your db?

Answer (score 1):

For so many records, I won't recommend Paging. You can show Top 20 recently added records and provide options to filter out records. A user can enter keywords. ReQuery and ReBind the GridView with this new result set.

You might also consider using [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/PetaPoco), a Micro-ORM, which will help you fetch paged result.

Comment: PetaPoco looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

With so many records, you really need to take into account the exact queries being run to pull back the data.

There are numerous ways of doing data paging ( http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10434/sql-server-server-side-paging-with-rownumber-function.aspx ).  However, the "best" way is dependent on the exact version of SQL Server you are running.

Essentially, the solutions boil down to you passing a page number and number of records per page through some type of query.  Usually a stored procedure as the query can be quite messy.

Once there, you have an option.  Either send the total record count back as an OUT parameter in your query and the result set back normally, or you send the total record count back as a column.  There are definitely efficiency concerns with both options as one way requires the query to be run twice and the other requires an extra column of data which increases network traffic.

Once you have that solved then you can figure out exactly how you want the UI to work.

Comment: Agreed.  I have an example using MVC WebGrid here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121735/asp-net-mvc3-webgrid-custom-server-side-sorting/10759799#10759799.  But my understanding is that GridView is easier since it's bound to a dataset instead of an enumerable of objects.  The sql from my example will be relevant, the webgrid details won't.